# Как пройти защиту от частых запросов с ip

Tags: php, curl

На хостинге запустил скрипт парсера, который часто обращается к сайту. Парсер работал покуда сайт его не заблокировал из-за частых обращений, и просит пройти каптчу гугла.

При этом HEADER получаю такой:

> TTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily Server: nginx/1.12.2 Date: Tue, 13 Feb 2018 06:34:43 GMT Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8 Connection: keep-alive Content-Length: 195 X-Ips-Suspection: Blacklisted Location: https://site.ru/captcha?url=aHR0cDovL3... Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31104000 X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block

Мой код cURL парсера:

```
function curl($host, $referer = null){
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 5.1; U; ru) Presto/2.9.168 Version/11.51");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $host);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1000);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    $html = curl_exec($ch);
    echo curl_error($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $html;
}
```

На другом хостинге этот парсер работает. Видимо как-то блокирует, может по ip.

Как обойти эту блокировку? Что можно подменить и как?

Comment: Стандартный совет использовать прокси и проверять статус ответа если снова забанят, менять прокси на следующую.

Comment: А не надо чужие сайты парсить :Р

Comment: или уменьшить частоту обращения парсера

Comment: @EvgeniyA я пытался сделать так `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, "31.130.200.164:443");` , менял разные прокси. получаю ответы типа: **Received HTTP code 400 from proxy after CONNECT**

Comment: Эта ошибка может значит все что угодно. В том числе и проблемы на строне прокси сервера. Возможно необходим добавить тип прокси curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_SOCKS5);